# what is cool in jboss's jmx-console?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, jboss, jmx

I like JNDIView that shows me all JNDI's, is there anything usefull beside that in jmx-console?

P.S. I know i could make my own MBeans, but i want to know what default cool actions are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of stuff :-).

http://jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-10941

My favorites are definitely "[Generate a thread dump](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-9804)" and "[Display the memory pool usage](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-9882)".

EDIT: Almost forgot "[List thread CPU utilization](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-9883)".